# How can I collect large amounts of python code for datasets?

Tags: python, dataset

I'm looking for a ready-made dataset that has various examples of Python code in it, or a simple solution that will help me create such a dataset. Is anyone able to help me?

I try to find already created datasets but nothing great.

Comment: How about https://github.com/search?q=python&type=repositories?

Comment: What makes such a dataset "great" or "not great"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any ready-made datesets, but I think the best way is to use Github and collect your code examples from there. There are some good ones; there are more than you need, and you can collect exactly what you want.

You could use web scraping tools such as Scrapy and BS4 to scrape GitHub's repositories that meet your quality standards.

Or you can make a list out of the repositories you find suitable and then write a script that scrapes the code from their repo which can be done by checking for desired extensions in the "file and folders section" of a repo and then clicking on every folder and checking the extensions again (you can distinguish folders from files using sth like the classes maybe or just use the icon)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Use [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). It's a site full of datasets for machine learning and data analysis. Here you can find great datasets and how you can use them. You can also see other projects related to data.